# BeautifulSoup: how to scrape meta tag description content

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i am trying to scrape the contents of a website's meta description.

example:

```
<meta name="description" content="This is the home page meta description.">
```

the output that i'm looking for is: "**This is the home page meta description.**"

my code is:

```
raw_html = simple_get(companyUrl)
html = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
x = html.select('meta', {'name' : 'description'})  ## this line errors out
```

can someone point me in the right direction?

(also - is it my imagination, or are BeautifulSoup tutorials/documentation not up to the level of other languages/applications?)

Comment: You're confusing `.select()` with `.find_all()`. Either use `find_all` or change your selector.

Comment: @t.m.adam - i guess that's what i am asking: how do i format my selector to capture tag=meta and name=description?

Comment: OK - i've brute forced a solution, but i am hoping that there's a more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: Why don't you use the selector in Martin's answer below?

Comment: OK - i've brute forced a solution, but i am hoping that there's a more elegant way of doing this.

raw_html = simple_get(companyUrl)
html = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
x = str(html.find_all("meta", attrs={"name": "description"}))
beg = x.find('content="') + 9
x = x[beg : ]
end = x.find('"')
x = x[ : end]

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. You can get the text of an attriibute with `tag[attribute]`. For example: `content = html.select_one("meta[name='description']")['content']` all in one line.

Comment: THANK YOU martin gergov and tm adam - this did the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a css selector like so:

```
x = html.select('meta[name="description"]')
print(x[0].attrs["content"])
```

Read more about css selectors [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp):

Answer (score 1):

Using `BeautifulSoup`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<meta name="description" content="This is the home page meta description.">"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
content = soup.find('meta', {'name':'description'}).get('content')
print(content)  # STDOUT: This is the home page meta description.
```

An alternate way using **regex**

```
import re

content = re.findall(r"content=\"(.*?)\"", html)
```

**NOTE:** regex parses faster and `findall` will return list of values of all content attributes defined at given *html*